# Read gzipped S3 object in chunks

Tags: boto3, python-3.7

I have some code currently working that uses boto3 to iterate through lines of a text file in S3 by using `s3_object.get()["Body"].iter_lines()`.  Is there any way to do something similar with a gzipped text file?  I have seen examples such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/59635286/177333, but as far as I can tell they load the whole file into memory.  Is there any way to do this in chunks?  I was hoping boto3 would detect the gzip header and do it automatically, but when trying to decode I got the expected `UnicodeDetectError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1` error.